# context data is not passed from django TemplateView to Template

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I have two models: `Address` and  `AddressHistory` , with one to many relationship. I have created a form to allow user to Add address history, where I am using an `inlineformset` for `Address`, but when template is rendered, `AddressHistory` form is displayed for inline `AddressForm`. Here is my view class:

I have two models: `Address` and  `AddressHistory` , with one to many relationship. I have created a form to allow user to Add address history, where I am using an inlineformset for `Address`, but when I render the template, `AddressHistory` form is displayed for inline `AddressForm`. Here is my view class:

```py
class AddHistoryView(generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = "history/add_history.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs: Any) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        AddressHistoryFormset = formset_factory(forms.AddressHistoryForm, extra=1)
        AddressFormset = inlineformset_factory(
            Address, AddressHistory, fields=("__all__"), extra=1
        )
        if self.request.method == "POST":
            address_history_formset = AddressHistoryFormset(
                self.request.POST, prefix="addresshistory"
            )
            address_formset = AddressFormset(self.request.POST, prefix="address")            
            if (
                address_history_formset.is_valid()
                and address_formset.is_valid()                
            ):
                address_history_formset.save()
                address_formset.save()                
        else:
            address_history_formset = AddressHistoryFormset(prefix="addresshistory")
            address_formset = AddressFormset(prefix="address")         
        context["address_history_formset"] = address_history_formset
        context["address_formset"] = address_formset
        return context
```

```py
class AddressHistoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.AddressHistory
        fields = [
            "from_day",
            "to_day",
            "address",
            "person",
            "arriving_entry",
            "departing_entry",
        ]


class AddressForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Address
        fields = [
            "address_id",
            "line1",
            "line2",
            "city",
            "state",
            "country",
            "zipcode",
            "address_type",
        ]
```

add_history.html

```html
{% block content %}
    <h2>Add address history</h2>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ address_history_formset.management_form }}
        {{ address_formset.management_form}}
        {% for ah_form in address_history_formset%}
            {{ah_form.as_p}}
            <h3>Add Address</h3>
            {{ address_formset.management_form}}
            {% for a_form in address_formset %}
                {{a_form.as_p}}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-secondary">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

`Address` model

```py
class Address(BaseModel):
    address_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    line1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    line2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    zipcode = models.IntegerField(10)
    address_type = models.ForeignKey(AddressType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.line1}, {self.city}, {self.state}"
```

`AddressHistory` model

```py
class AddressHistory(BaseModel):
    ah_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    from_day = models.DateField()
    to_day = models.DateField()
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        Person, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="address_history_set"
    )
    arriving_entry = models.OneToOneField(
        TravelEntry,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name="arriving_entry_set",
    )
    departing_entry = models.OneToOneField(
        TravelEntry,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        related_name="departing_entry_set",
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.address}"
```

This is what is rendered on the screen:
[image]

I'm learning django and Python, as per my understanding, `Address` form should be loaded below Add Address, so that user can add corresponding address if needed when adding address history.

Comment: The address field inside AddressHistory is foreignkey of Address model, so is correct address appear in AddressHistory form. In fact, the address is an object of model Address.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you. But, if you are asking if address is populated currently in `AddressHistory` form, yes, I can see all the addresses in address dropdown.

Comment: Well, following your last doubt, I answered why the address field is showed in AddressHistory and not in Address form. But your first question 'AddressHistory form is displayed for inline AddressForm' what do you mean by that? Do you want render the form differently?

Comment: I created `AddHistoryView` for user to add their address histories. Now, while adding address history they may want to add a new address. So I want address history form to be displayed on top with inline address forms. Do I have to change anything to achieve this?